# Google Maps application crashes when the application starts to launch

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to show Google Map in my android application. So i followed the instruction at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2  and build a project accordingly. After running the project I am getting the following error in my log cat

```
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274): Failed to inflate
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.arifhaq.googlemapproject-2.apk]
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-10 17:41:13.589: E/ActivityThread(1274):     ... 19 more
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arifhaq.googlemapproject/com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     ... 11 more
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.arifhaq.googlemapproject-2.apk]
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-10 17:41:13.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1274):     ... 19 more
```

I tried to find solution for this in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong. what need to be done to make my project work. bellow is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arifhaq.googlemapproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<permission
    android:name="com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.permision.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.permision.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="BFzaS.......not posting here...." />
</application>
```

the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.arifhaq.googlemapproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  `android:minSdkVersion="8"` so you should go with `SupportMapFragment` and also 
 extends your `MainActivity` to `FragmentActivity`

and also change

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I did what you wrote above but its now giving me java.lang.ClassNotFound exception

Comment: @user3393926 Did you reference `google_play_services_lib` in your project?

Comment: Yes I did it at the beginning

Comment: Yes i did that earlier and even now copied your solution to my layout file and ran the whole project again and getting the same  java.lang.ClassNotFound exception

Answer (score 0):

Add This Line In The Parent Layout in Map Activity
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Did that but now getting java.lang.ClassNotFound exception

Comment: please write Class Entry in AndroidMenifest.Add google PlayService library in your project

Comment: try this android:name="com.arifhaq.googlemapproject.MainActivity"